# Difference between accessing a constant by self or class name on PHP?

Tags: php, oop

What is the difference, if any, between accessing a constant using self vs class name.

```
class MyClass {

    const MAGIC_NUMBER = 4;

    protected $number;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->number = self::$MAGIC_NUMBER;
    }
}
```

vs

```
class MyClass {

    const MAGIC_NUMBER = 4;

    protected $number;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->number = MyClass::MAGIC_NUMBER;
    }
}
```

Comment: You made a mess with `$` sign. Constants do not have it, and `protected` does not have it in front, but `protected $number` should have it. And I do not think that you can access constant by `$this->` Look here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this straight from my head to SO. We don't realize how much we rely on IDE for these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes. I think the question is still pretty valid even if there are formatting issues? My bad if that offended anybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between them.
Also you should not put `$` there:

```
const MAGIC_NUMBER = 4;
protected $number;
```

Answer (score 2):

The examples you gave are invalid, and I think you might be confusing constants and static variables.

Class constants:

```
class MyClass {
    const MAGIC_NUMBER = 4;

    protected $number;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->number = self::MAGIC_NUMBER; // or MyClass::MAGIC_NUMBER
    }
}
```

Static class variables:

```
class MyClass2 {
    static $MAGIC_NUMBER = 4;

    protected $number;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->number = MyClass2::$MAGIC_NUMBER; // or self::$MAGIC_NUMBER
    }
}
```

The main difference is that MyClass2::$MAGIC_NUMBER can be changed, while in both cases the values can be accessed without requiring an instance of the class.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I made a mistake with the examples. I got them down from my head to SO. Will think about doing that again. Anyhow, thanks for the complete answer.